# How to select vendor when using macchanger in linux

Tags: linux, mac-spoofing

Currently, I am using this command to spoof my MAC address:

macchanger eth0 -A

However, I want to be able to select which vendor I use. I know that the switch -l displays a list of all available vendors, but say I want to use one from Cisco, what command do I use to actually use that specific vendor rather than the system choosing a random vendor for me each time?

Comment: The first 2x3 digits determine who the vendor is. So you can set them manually by using -m

Answer (score 2):

You could add a function like this to .bashrc
Then you can: macspoof Apple eth0

```
macspoof () {
  Vendor=$(macchanger -l | grep $1 | shuf -n 1 | awk '{print $3}')
  Tail=$(echo $RANDOM | md5sum | sed 's/.\{2\}/&:/g' | cut -c 1-8)
  Mac="$Vendor:$Tail"
  sudo macchanger -m $Mac $2
}
```